# Java Intelij Idea how to add gutter icon?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, icons, gutter

I have a problem with rendering gutter icons, in my IntelliJ idea plugin project. 
[image: problem]

I want to render gutter icon next to a line number, but it renders only small rectangle. Gutter icon path is loaded properly and gutter icon size is 12x12px, format png. Can you help me?

My code:

```java
public static void addLineHighlight(Document document, int lineNumber,
                                        String text) {


        Icon highlightIcon = IconLoader.getIcon("META-INF/fail.png");

        addGutterIcon(getRangeHighlighter(document, lineNumber), highlightIcon, text);
    }


    @NotNull
    private static RangeHighlighter getRangeHighlighter(Document document, int lineNumber) {
        MarkupModel markupModel = getMarkupModel(document);
        TextAttributes textAttributes = getTextAttributes();

        RangeHighlighter highlighter;
        highlighter = markupModel.addLineHighlighter(lineNumber, 66 , textAttributes);
        return highlighter;
    }

    private static void addGutterIcon(@NotNull RangeHighlighter highlighter, Icon icon, String text) {

        highlighter.setGutterIconRenderer(new GutterIconRenderer() {
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return 0;
            }

            @NotNull
            @Override
            public Icon getIcon() {
                return icon;
            }
        });

    }

    private static MarkupModel getMarkupModel(Document document) {
        return DocumentMarkupModel.forDocument(document, TestSingleton.getInstance().getProject(), true);
    }

    @NotNull
    private static TextAttributes getTextAttributes() {
        TextAttributes textAttributes = null;
        textAttributes = new TextAttributes();
        textAttributes.setBackgroundColor(JBColor.RED);
        textAttributes.setErrorStripeColor(JBColor.RED);
        return textAttributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should be using **com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.LineMarkerProvider**. See [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000164564-Insert-Gutter-icon) and [this example](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/blob/master/tutorials/custom_language_support/line_marker_provider.md)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be using **com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.LineMarkerProvider**.

See [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000164564-Insert-Gutter-icon) and [this example](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/blob/master/tutorials/custom_language_support/line_marker_provider.md).